# How to select a table from a function param

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the function:

```
test(IN _partition)
```

Inside my function I would like to append the '_partition' to the beginning of my table name.

```
FROM table_ + '_partition'
```

The end result:

```
select * from test(12345);
```

This function will query the table: table_12345

Comment: It can be done with dynamic sql (winthin PL/pgSQL context) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 1):

You need PL/PgSQL dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` and the `format` function, e.g.

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I', _partition);
```

However, this is a mark of a design that will probably be painful to work with.

Have you looked at PostgreSQL's table inheritance features?